# Is it possible to send a mail with PHP (or JavaScript) using a 3rd party service?

Tags: php, email

I want to send customers a mail if they register, buy sth etc. but my server cannot send mails itself.
Is there any way to use a 3rd party service? I haven't found any.

Sorry if my English isn't that good but i'm no native speaker.

Comment: What exactly did you search? Search for "Transactional e-mail service" There are many: Mandrill, Postmark etc.

Comment: i'm searching an easy-to-use 3rd party mailing service - i'll search for Mandrill and Postmark - it could be that my search engine hasn't showed me them cause i'm not using google

Comment: To sending email , please use SMTP service . Search for SMTP service  provider and you will get many results (PHP supports using an external SMTP service to send email by module such as PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use javascript mailto :
window.location.href = "mailto:mail@example.org";
or the php and smtp using the mail() function.